# How to remove empty space from front of JSON object?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I am trying to process a large JSON file using the follow code:

```
dctx = zst.ZstdDecompressor(max_window_size=2147483648)
with open(filename+".zst", 'rb') as infile, open(outpath, 'wb') as outfile:
    dctx.copy_stream(infile, outfile)
    
with pd.read_json(filename+".json", lines=True, chunksize=5000) as reader:
        reader
        # Making list of column headers
        df_titles = []
        for chunk in reader:
            chunk_titles = list(chunk.keys())
            df_titles.extend(chunk_titles)
            df_titles = list(set(df_titles))
```

However, when I attempt to run the code, I get an error message: `ValueError: Expected object or value`. The file is formatted with one JSON object per line, and looking at the JSON file itself, it seems the issue is that one of the JSON objects has a bunch of empty space in front of it. [image: Empty space][image]

If I manually delete the 'nul' line, the file processes with no issues. However, for the sake of reproducibility, I would like to be able to address the issue from within my code itself. I'm pretty new to working in Python, and I have tried googling the issue, but solutions seem to focus on removing white space from the beginning of JSON values, rather than the start of a line in this kind of file. Is there any easy way to deal with this issue either when decompressing the initial file, or reading the decompressed file in?

Comment: What's *generating* the file? That's what should be fixed.

Comment: U+0000 isn't valid in JSON at all, so you should be able to simply strip it from the file anywhere you find it.

Comment: was it in there before compressing, `0x00` is not a space character, in text files it is illegal

Comment: I didn't compress the file--it's from the Reddit Pushshift dataset so I downloaded it and decompressed it using the first few lines of the code above. How can I strip it or avoid it when I decompress?